# rebar erlang package mnesia replication dynamically

Tags: erlang, replication, database-replication, mnesia, rebar3

**Problem Statement**

I have created an Erlang package using Rebar3. It is a tar ball which just need to be put in desired OS and get started once you start the node. So like wise there are two nodes, of same kind, in two different linux boxes. Those are not mnesia replicated, how do i make then replicated?

```
change_config(Config, Value)
```

This function in mnesia module would be ok if other node is completely empty schema, but that's not the case with me.

Please let me know how can i resolve this problem?